# How to generate unique random value for each user in symfony and add it to database

Tags: php, symfony

I am developing an enterprise based application. Here when the end-user registers via this application i will give a unique random number(8 digit),
which I used to generate a 8-digit and mail it to him.

Expectation :

I want to make the number unique for each registered user. It should be random number

I already implement random number generator but its not unique for all.
if any one knows please help me to solve this instead of random number generator, Any suggestion...?

Comment: You could hash over the combination of: userId + sessionId + even_name + current_time

Comment: @Tarun I am not familiar with symfony, but is there a way of making an autoincrement function ( which means there will never be a duplicate value ) and hash that autoincrement number.

Comment: @Tarun its symfony with postgres DB, my user id is 32-bit UUID

Comment: @tomm ya exactly i need autoincrement number

Answer (score 2):

There are several options like `uniqid` which generate an unique identifier. However `uniqid` has been proven to cause collisions in some cases. Adding `true` to the function call will add entropy to lower the amount of collisions. However I'd suggest you go with [`random_bytes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) or [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) instead as they are profoundly better at it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a Universally unique identifiers (UUID). The [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) libary is a good tool for that. Add another column to the "users" table with a UUID (e.g. user_uuid). Generate a new UUID and save the value there.

Example:

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

// Generate a version 4 (random) UUID object
$uuid4 = Uuid::uuid4();
echo $uuid4->toString(); // i.e. 25769c6c-d34d-4bfe-ba98-e0ee856f3e7a
```